# how to update with modal bootstrap and checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, checkbox

hey guys how can i update multiple rows with checkbox and display modal bootstrap after pressing update button?

example like this:

- I checked the line with the checkbox
  [image]
- After that I press "Pindah Department" or in english "Move Departemen"
  [image]
- actually I do not need the edit book () function, I only need one function and the funtion it can call modal bootstrap pops up, to update from the dropdown menu"
  [image]
- i forgot to change save button to call function prepareData(), pop up appears, but I do not know what it is
  [image]

I can only edit it one by one, with Modal Bootstrap, how can i be like above that?

this is my view:

```
<table id="emp_id" class="table table-bordered dt-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th width="1%" align="center"><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" id="checkAll" name="checkAll" /></th>
                    <th width="1%" align="center">No.</th>
                    <th width="1%" align="center">Edit</th>
                    <th width="20%" align="center">Nama Lengkap</th>
                    <th width="5%" align="center">No Induk</th>
                    <th width="10%" align="center">Jenis Kelamin</th>
                    <th width="5%" align="center">PIN</th> 
                    <th width="20%" align="center">Departemen</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php 

                foreach($data as $d){

                ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <input class="childbox" width="1%" type="checkbox" name="msg[]" id="id" align="center" value="<?php echo $d['emp_id'] ?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%" align="center"><?php echo $d['emp_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><button  class="btn btn-light" onclick="edit_book(<?php echo $d['emp_id'];?>)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button></td>
                    <td class="data-check"><?php echo $d['first_name']; ?></td>
                    <td class="data-check"><?php echo $d['nik']; ?></td>
                    <td class="data-check"><?php echo $d['gender']=='0' ? 'Laki-Laki' : 'Perempuan'; ?></td>
                    <td class="data-check"><?php echo $d['pin']; ?></td>
                    <td class="data-check"><?php echo $d['dept_name']; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <th width="1%" align="center"><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" id="checkAll" name="checkAll" /></th>
                    <th width="1%" align="center">No.</th>
                    <th width="1%" align="center">Edit</th>
                    <th width="20%" align="center">Nama Lengkap</th>
                    <th width="5%" align="center">No Induk</th>
                    <th width="10%" align="center">Jenis Kelamin</th>
                    <th width="5%" align="center">PIN</th> 
                    <th width="20%" align="center">Departemen</th>
                  </tr>
                </tfoot>                    
              </table>
```

this is my script to bring up modal bootstrap and for checkbox functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready( function () {

          $('#emp_id').DataTable( {
              "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
          } );


      $("input[name='checkAll']").click(function() {
            var checked = $(this).attr("checked");
            $("#emp_id tr td input:checkbox").attr("checked", checked); });

      } );

      function toggle(id) { 

        checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('msg[]'); 
        for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) { 
          checkboxes[i].checked = id.checked; 
        } 
      }

      function add_book()
      {
        save_method = 'add';
        $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
        $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
      //$('.modal-title').text('Add Person'); // Set Title to Bootstrap modal title
      }


      function edit_book(id)
        {
          save_method = 'update';
          $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals

          //Ajax Load data from ajax
          $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('proses/ajax_edit/')?>/" + id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data)
            {

                $('[name="emp_id"]').val(data.emp_id);
                $('[name="dept_id_auto"]').val(data.dept_id_auto);


                $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
                $('.modal-title').text('Edit Departemen'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error get data from ajax');
            }
        });
        }

      function save()
        {
          var url;
          if(save_method == 'add')
          {
              url = "<?php echo site_url('proses/book_add')?>";
          }
          else
          {
            url = "<?php echo site_url('proses/book_update')?>";
          }

           // ajax adding data to database
              $.ajax({
                url : url,
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#form').serialize(),
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data)
                {
                   //if success close modal and reload ajax table
                   $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                  location.reload();// for reload a page
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert('Error adding / update data');
                }
            });
        }
      </script>
```

and this is my modal bootstrap :

```
<div id="modal_form" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Tambah Siswa</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body form">
              <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
                <input type="hidden" value="" name="emp_id"/>
                  <div class="form-body">

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Pilih Departemen Baru</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <select name="dept_id_auto" class="form-control pull-right">
                            <?php
                            foreach($groups as $row)
                            {
                                echo '<option name="dept_id_auto" value="'.$row['dept_id_auto'].'">'.$row['dept_name'].'</option>';
                            }
                          ?>             
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
```

and this is my controller :

```
public function book_update()
{
    $data = array(
            'dept_id_auto' => $this->input->post('dept_id_auto'),
        );
    $this->Pindah_dept_model->book_update(array('devid_auto' => $this->input->post('devid_auto')), $data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}

public function ajax_edit($id)
{
    $data = $this->Pindah_dept_model->get_by_id($id);



    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

and this is my model :

```
public function get_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('emp_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();
}

public function book_update($where, $data)
{
    $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

hey Eiji can you modify this code because, if I use this code I can do multiple update rows, but this code does not display modal bootstrap, it's just this code directly call the function in the controller, but have the same concept only this code can not display modal bootstrap, please

```
function update(id)
          {
              var list_id = [];
              $("#id:checked").each(function() {
                      list_id.push(parseInt(this.value));
              });
          console.info(JSON.stringify(list_id));

              if(list_id.length > 0)
              {
                  if(confirm('Are you sure update this '+list_id.length+' data?'))
                  {
                      $.ajax({
                          type: 'POST',
                          data: {'devid_auto': list_id},
                          url: '<?php echo site_url('setting/mesin_update')?>',
                          success: function(result)
                          {
                              var hasil = result.replace(/\s/g,'');
                              if(hasil == 'y')
                              {
                                alert("Data Berhasil di Update");
                                location.reload();
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  alert('Failed.');
                              }

                          },
                          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                          {
                              alert('Error update data');
                          }
                      });
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  alert('no data selected');
              }

          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Small correction in your html, Please delete the `id="id"`, this is a big mistakes, because the id **shoud be unique**.

```
<input class="childbox" width="1%" type="checkbox" name="msg[]" align="center" value="" data-userid="<?php echo $d['emp_id'] ?>"/>
```

1. you have to define which of your line has been checked.

   ```
   var user_id_list = []; //this will be the collection of id

   //for each checked checkbox do...
   $("input[type=checkbox].childbox").each(function(){

      //get the user id value of the line
      var the_userid = $(this).data('userid');

      //add it to our collection
      user_id_list.push( the_userid );

   });
   ```
2. you find what is the option selected.

   ```
   var new_dept = $("#modal_form select[name=dept_id_auto] option:selected").val();
   ```
3. You have to pass all this to your ajax request. So there is your ajax and a new function to add

   ```
   function save()
   {
     var url;
     if(save_method == 'add')
     {
         url = "<?php echo site_url('proses/book_add')?>";
     }
     else
     {
       url = "<?php echo site_url('proses/book_update')?>";
     }

      // ajax adding data to database
         $.ajax({
           url : url,
           type: "POST",
           data: prepareData(), //<-- here we call it
           dataType: "JSON",
           success: function(data)
           {
              //if success close modal and reload ajax table
              $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
             location.reload();// for reload a page
           },
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
           {
               alert('Error adding / update data');
           }
       });
   }

   function prepareData(){

       $data = [];

       var user_id_list = []; //this will be the collection of id

       //for each checked checkbox do...
       $("input[type=checkbox].childbox").each(function(){

           //get the user id value of the line
           var the_userid = $(this).data('userid');

           //add it to our collection
           user_id_list.push( the_userid );

       });

       //select the new debt value
       var new_dept = $("#modal_form select[name=dept_id_auto] option:selected").val();

       //we pass all the data to an array
       data.push('user_id_list',user_id_list);
       data.push('new_dept', new_dept);

       return data;
   }
   ```

Now, in your controller, you should have two post data : 
* new_dept, which content an int of the new dept
* user_id_list, which is an array of id.

So you just need to adapt your model and it's over.

---

Change the line

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <!-- change here -->
    <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="prepareData()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <!-- end change -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Then, in your javascript function `prepareData()`

```
//we pass all the data to an array
data.push('user_id_list',user_id_list);
data.push('new_dept', new_dept);

//add this line for the debugging
alert( JSON.stringify(data) ) 
//this will display the current data value, even if it's an array/object or whatever

return data;
```

Comment: it's like you're updating quickly, no need to update the line one by one, just by checking the line and pressing the "Pindah Department or Move Departement in English" button then Modal Bootstrap appears, and you choose in dropdown, want to move to what department
example you select 2 lines with value "ADMIN" and will replace it with value "STAFF". So you do not need to change it one line after line

Comment: Hmm I not sure of what you are asking for. Your probleme is : With your solution, you have to refresh the page after each update, but you want to update without any reloading?
Am I right?

Comment: i mean, I want to make multiple updates by checking the line, pressing the "move department" and modal bootstrap will appear and you just choose to change it with what value

Comment: Okey! I get it. Sorry for that,

Comment: I need the HTML of the list, where thethe checkboxs are... Can you add it please?

Comment: see my post, I can only make like that, can you edit the script as I want? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48374085/how-to-update-multple-rows-checkbox-with-one-button-codeigniter

Comment: it seems that in my post it is the same, only after I press the update button it directly call the controller function, I mean that after I press update button appears bootstrap capital and choose value to change it

Comment: I know this is very confusing because I can not explain what I mean -_-

Comment: Don't worry, I get it ^^

Comment: where i put this code ? `var new_dept = $("#modal_form select[name=dept_id_auto] option:selected").val();` ?

Comment: I put everything in a new function `prepareData`, look at the end of my post

Comment: oh i understand, so I just added the two functions you made in the 3rd number?

Comment: so I have to call what function on my button?

Comment: exactly. Sorry it's a little messy

Comment: No, actually, the function is called by the "save" function. If you like closely, the function prepareData is called at the line "data : " in your ajax function

Comment: oh so after i checked my line and added new button then call function save ()?, am i right?

Comment: You just need to add your `save()` function to a trigger. When we click on the button of your modal, the `save()` is called. but your code already do that, so, it should be okey

Comment: what is different??

Comment: I've called the edit_book () function in the "move department" button, then modal bootstrap can come out, but when I change the value in the dropdown, and press the save button it call save function in script, in the modal bootstrap, but the button can not be pressed, and the value not changed ?, what should I do?

Comment: when I see the error code in the console it says " `data.push('user_id_list',user_id_list);` Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
and on save in this part `data: prepareData(),`
I do not know what that means but the error is yellow in the console

Comment: yeah it have a typo... `$data = [];` replace it with `var data = [];`. First ligne of prepareData, my mistake.

Comment: but Eiji, why the line I checked with the checkbox and I press the "move department" data is not the same ?, but the other?

Comment: after I checked and pressed the "move department" button and changed the value in the dropdown and hit the save button, the button worked but the value did not change

Comment: okey, so there maybe a probleme during the update of the value. Can you replace temporary the `save()` calling in your button by `prepareData()` and add `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` just before the `return`, and take a screen of what is write please?

Comment: can you re-explain, I do not understand: D

Comment: so I should add `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` before `return` in fuction `prepareData()`, im i right ?

Comment: look my post, still the same after I added the code `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: there is no popup?

Comment: `alert( console.log(data) ) ;` be like this?

Comment: oh wait in`["user_id_list",[2,3,4,6, ....]]`, that's true with the numbers in each line, and `['new_dept', "3"]` matches the value "ADMIN" in the dropdown, if in the database value "ADMIN" is numbered 3

Comment: Okey, so, it work. You can remove the console.log and deplace your html by save() as before. :]

Comment: but it still choose the wrong line as the first one and, after I finished change the value in dropdown, value did not change it still same

Answer (score -1):

you can use my code for referenction

```
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#r<?php echo $rule2->id_forward;?>">Edit </button>
    <?=anchor('guru/hapus_rule/'.$rule2->id_forward,'Hapus',['class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-sm'])?>
</td>
<div class="modal modal-success" id="r<?php echo $rule2->id_forward;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" align="center">Edit Rule</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php echo form_open_multipart('guru/ubah_rule/'.$rule2->id_forward);?>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Kondisi">Kondisi 1</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="kondisi">
                            <option value="">Pilih</option>
                            <?php foreach ($kondisi as $key) {?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $key->nama_kondisi?>" <?php if($rule2->gejala_1==$key->nama_kondisi){echo "selected";} ?>><?php echo $key->nama_kondisi; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Kondisi_2">Kondisi 2</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="kondisi_2">
                            <option value="">Pilih</option>
                            <?php foreach ($kondisi as $key) {?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $key->nama_kondisi?>" <?php if($rule2->gejala_2==$key->nama_kondisi){echo "selected";} ?>><?php echo $key->nama_kondisi; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Kondisi_3">Kondisi 3</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="kondisi_3">
                            <option value="">Pilih</option>
                            <?php foreach ($kondisi as $key) {?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $key->nama_kondisi?>" <?php if($rule2->gejala_3==$key->nama_kondisi){echo "selected";} ?>><?php echo $key->nama_kondisi; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Kondisi_4">Kondisi 4</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="kondisi_4">
                            <option value="">Pilih</option>
                            <?php foreach ($kondisi as $key) {?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $key->nama_kondisi?>" <?php if($rule2->gejala_4==$key->nama_kondisi){echo "selected";} ?>><?php echo $key->nama_kondisi; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Kondisi_5">Kondisi 5</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="kondisi_5">
                            <option value="">Pilih</option>
                            <?php foreach ($kondisi as $key) {?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $key->nama_kondisi?>" <?php if($rule2->gejala_5==$key->nama_kondisi){echo "selected";} ?>><?php echo $key->nama_kondisi; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="hasil">Hasil</label>
                        <input type="text" name="hasil" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $rule2->hasil; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="artikel">Artikel</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="id_artikel">
                            <option value="">Pilih</option>
                            <?php foreach ($artikel as $data_rule) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $data_rule->id_artikel; ?>" <?php if($rule2->id_artikel==$data_rule->id_artikel){echo "selected";} ?> ><?php echo $data_rule->judul; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputFile">File Pembelajaran</label>
                        <input type="file" name="berkas" id="exampleInputFile">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please don't post long-code-only answers, highlight the most important bits so that it's clear for your fellow coders how to implement/modify what's requested. Best regards